# How to convert Json data directly into xml - standardized way?

Tags: 8

I'm having a Json:

```
[{"S":"a","D":"b"},{"S":"s1","D":"m1"},{"S":"2","D":"3"},{"S":"4","D":"5"}]
```

And I want it to convert into XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Us>
    <U1>
        <S>a</S>
        <D>b</D>
    </U1>
    <U1>
        <S>s1</S>
        <D>m1</D>
    </U1>
</Us>
```

I know the php way, first decoding json using `Json_decode()` and a bunch of `foreach loop` that finally generate XML.

But I want in Drupal way. There is a module `serialization` in core of Drupal 8. But don't know how can I take the services from that module in my custom one.

Also, I got a link, How to get it done using [symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), but again it seems like Drupal 8 standards are lacking somewhere by me.

What's the right approach to achieve this in Drupal way.

Comment: Is your data normalized and does it need to be denormalized into data that Drupal understands (such as a node, user, taxonomy term, etc...)?

Comment: Serializer is also a perfectly fine way of doing this in Drupal 8. The serialization module uses that component.

Comment: It's like, when saving, I saved into database in json format but now when I'm retrieving, I want it in xml. It's fine with me to decode it first and get an array structure, (I'm getting 1 array of multiple objects), but now how to convert it into xml is a little challenging with best approach.

Answer (score 1):

The Serializer component is a tool in your Drupal toolbox that should be used when you need to serialize and deserialize data from and to Drupal data such as entities. Unfortunately you cannot deserialize into a \StdClass without implementing your own normalizer.

Inject the `serializer` service into your class, and use the `serialize` method to normalize the non-Drupal decoded JSON array into XML.

```
// Inject this instead of using \Drupal
$serializer = \Drupal::get('serializer');
// Use json_decode or @4k4's example above and use associative arrays instead of object.
$json = json_decode('[{"S":"a","D":"b"},{"S":"s1","D":"m1"},{"S":"2","D":"3"},{"S":"4","D":"5"}]', TRUE);
// Unfortunately it seems that for an array serializer xml_root_node_name won't work so wrap $json in the root name.
$data = ['US' => $json];
// Serialize into XML.
$xml = $serializer->serialize(
  $data,
  'xml',
  ['xml_root_node_name' => 'US']);
```